# A Sublime Text extension to show PHP warnings and errors

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I installed Sublime Text 2 recently, and I'm still adapting. I've already installed the Package Control and the most of PHP extensions. I wish a one that would underline the syntaxes errors, like Netbeans does. Is there a package that can do this?

Comment: Sublimetext is an -advanced- editor, netbeans is an IDE, there is a huge difference between the 2.

Comment: Here's a forum thread about it: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=9103

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) (it checks PHP syntax using `php -l`).

Comment: @Kakitori Type `php --help` and you'll know (`l` is short for lint).