# How to identify where the "Error" is located in a script file using Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, syntax-error, sublimetext3

I am using ST3 on a PHP script file.

The lower left corner indicates I have "1 error" somewhere in the script.

[image]

How can I locate where the error is and what it is?

*Note: the "Line 612, Column 13" simply tells me where the cursor is at this moment. It is not where the error is located.*

Comment: you could use some plugins to help you debug

Comment: Ok, nice idea @user37202. But first, why or how would ST3 know if there is an error without also being able to take you to it? Sounds like an incomplete implementation to me. Second, do you know of any plugins to do that?

Comment: see http://wasil.org/sublime-text-3-perfect-php-development-set-up conatins many useful plugins

Comment: it could be very wide range of errors and also depending on plugins you already use it could check for links it could use unreachable variable at some point of run time it is too wide [Github seems to have a solution](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SublimeLinter-php](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-php), This plugin  provides an interface to `php -l`. It will be used with files that have the “PHP”, “HTML”, or “HTML 5” syntax.

Usage Example

[image]

There is also [Javascript](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-jshint) , [JSON](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-json) and [CSS](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-csslint) versions

Answer (score 1):

refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433423/php-syntax-check-in-sublime-text-editor) to install SL PHP lint plugin, it will tell you where the error is

Comment: and also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217157/a-sublime-text-extension-to-show-php-warnings-and-errors